# Fire Event on change not firing the search

Tags: html, excel, vba

In my online interface there is a client search. At the point when I embed PAN. Search motor discover the client with that PAN and I select something similar (When I select it every client has some extraordinary id at backend, it reflecting for half second). When I Select a similar it divert me to the page where full detail of client is there. I needed to divert there. However, codes are not supporting.

HTML Codes

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: left;">
                        <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: right !important;">
                            <label for="CLIENT_ID">CLIENTS: </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite">1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span><input class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-autocomplete-loading" id="SEARCH_CLIENT_ID" style="width: 100% !important; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);" autocomplete="off">
                            <input id="hdnSEARCH_CLIENT_ID" type="hidden">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have taken a stab at fallowing Codes

```
IE.Document.getElementById("SEARCH_CLIENT_ID").Focus
IE.Document.getElementById("SEARCH_CLIENT_ID").Value = "ACPPL3488C"
IE.Document.getElementById("SEARCH_CLIENT_ID").FireEvent ("onchange")
IE.Document.getElementById("SEARCH_CLIENT_ID").selectedIndex = 1
```

In any case, its not working for me. generously control me my misstep

Comment: if you are passing value from code then on change event will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

Create `change` event using `Event constructor` and then dispatch the change event on target element using  `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()` method.

```js
const event = new Event('change');
const inputEle = document.getElementById("SEARCH_CLIENT_ID");

// Listen for the change event.
inputEle.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.value); // output: ACPPL3488C
}, false);

inputEle.focus();
inputEle.value = "ACPPL3488C";

// Dispatch the change event.
inputEle.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: left;">
                        <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: right !important;">
                            <label for="CLIENT_ID">CLIENTS: </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite">1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span><input class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-autocomplete-loading" id="SEARCH_CLIENT_ID" style="width: 100% !important; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);" autocomplete="off">
                            <input id="hdnSEARCH_CLIENT_ID" type="hidden">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Check [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) for more details.

Comment: Don't have idea about Excel VBA, you mentioned javascript and the solution works for that. I think you should remove `Javascript` tag in your question.

Comment: @QHarr please suggest